# Is it possible to get position of dom element relative parent window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get position of a DOM element relative parent window. Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: What do you mean by „DOM element relative parent window“?

Comment: I have an iframe in current document, I want to get position of element in this iframe relative it's parent window.

Comment: do you have access to iframe? If it's from another domain you won't be able to get inside it

Comment: Do you have any idea if I have access to iframe?

Answer (score 0):

`elem.offsetTop` and `elem.offsetLeft` will give you the position of the current element relative to its parent for block elements.

See this [description on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft) for details.

Comment: I have an iframe in current document, I want to get position of element in this iframe relative it's parent window.

Comment: @heyusysu - `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` will work on the iFrame element itself.  If you have code inside the iFrame itself that wants this info, then it's a little more complicated as you will have to get the containing iFrame element.